# Select XML attribute value found via another attribute value grouped with it.

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq

I'm brand new to doing anything with XML, so I don't know much terminology so sorry for the possibly badly worded question.

I have an XML file structured as so:

```
<userinfo>
    <id username="bobby" password="password123" email="booby@gmail.com" question="Favourite colour" answer="blue"></id>
    <id username="tommy" password="adc123" email="herpderp@gmail.com" question="first pets name" answer="arnold"></id>
</userinfo>
```

(Any suggested improvements to this would be appreciated)

I need to retrieve the question value as a string, based on a username.

I have some code interacting with the xml already, where I return a bool for the login, which just checks the info is there together:

```
public bool ValidLogin(string username, string password)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"K:\Sem2\Software Development in Application Frameworks\test stuff\text\loginDetails.xml");

    return doc.Descendants("id")
                .Where(id => id.Attribute("username").Value == username 
                        && id.Attribute("password").Value == password)
                .Any();
}
```

But that is using linq, I don't know how to get an actual value from xml.

It would be nice if it was as simple as something along the lines of:

```
 return doc.Descendants("id").Attribute("question").Value.Where(id => id.Attribute("username").Value == enteredUsername);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Select()` or `First()` or `Last()` or `Single()` to get values.

Ideally, you should have a class that matches your XML file:

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public string username {get;set;}
    public string password {get;set;}
    public string question {get;set;}
    public string email {get;set;}
    public string answer {get;set;}
}
```

Then change your method to something like this:

```
public UserInfo GetUserInfo(string username, string password)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"K:\Sem2\Software Development in Application Frameworks\test stuff\text\loginDetails.xml");

    return doc.Descendants("id")
                .Where(id => (string)id.Attribute("username") == username 
                        && (string)id.Attribute("password") == password)
                .Select(s => new UserInfo
                {
                    username = (string)s.Attribute("username"),
                    password = (string)s.Attribute("password"),
                    email = (string)s.Attribute("email"),
                    question = (string)s.Attribute("question"),
                    answer = (string)s.Attribute("answer")
                })
                .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Now in your calling method:

```
var userInfo = GetUserInfo(username, password);

// check if user information matches what's in the XML file. return an error if it doesnt.
if (userInfo == null)
   Console.WriteLine("incorrect username/password");

// you haven't clarified in your question what you're doing with it. But the value of 'question' is accessible like this:
Console.WriteLine(userInfo.question);
```

Comment: This is working great on one form, but I feel like a total noob, but how do I get the "userInfo.question" value on a different aspx form, I don't want to post the value in the url.

Comment: @Tom That's a different question. If you need the value on more than 1 ASPX page, you'll need to maintain some sort of state in your application. You might want to read up on Session state a bit, or look for some ASP.NET user authentication examples.

Comment: @Tom set your html form method to POST. (GET = URL querystring). The action should check if form = valid. if successful -> redirect to welcome page

Answer (score 1):

You can use methods like `Single` or `Select` to get at the elements and attributes that you are looking for. Take the following example I put together in LinqPad:

```
var xml = "<userinfo>"
    + "<id username=\"bobby\" password=\"password123\" email=\"booby@gmail.com\" question=\"Favourite colour\" answer=\"blue\"></id>"
    + "<id username=\"tommy\" password=\"adc123\" email=\"herpderp@gmail.com\" question=\"first pets name\" answer=\"arnold\"></id>"
    + "</userinfo>";
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var enteredUsername = "tommy";

//Get idElement by username using Single()
var idElement = xDoc.Descendants("id")
                .Single(id => id.Attribute("username").Value == enteredUsername);

//Get question and answer values from idElement
var question = idElement.Attributes().Single(i => i.Name == "question").Value;
var answer = idElement.Attributes().Single(i => i.Name == "answer").Value;
Console.WriteLine(question);
Console.WriteLine(answer);
```

Alternatively, you could select the values into an anonymous class using the following code:

```
var xml = "...";
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var enteredUsername = "tommy";
var qa = xDoc.Descendants("id")
                .Where(id => id.Attribute("username").Value == enteredUsername)
                .Select(id => new { 
                    Question = id.Attribute("question").Value,
                    Answer = id.Attribute("answer").Value})
                .Single();
Console.WriteLine(qa.Question);
Console.WriteLine(qa.Answer);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Problem with using plain Single() is that it throws an exception if values don't match.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I just used `Single()` to illustrate how the calls work without adding in the null checks you would need if you used `FirstOrDefault()`.